# Macro to send email using Gmail with contents from a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, email, smtp

I have agents that need to fill out a sales form that goes to another agent that does enrolments. So I have a script setup for a button when the agents click it, it sends an email to the other agent, but **I am not sure how to include the spreadsheet data**.

How can I do this?

Here is the code I have been using:

```
Sub sendemail()

    On Error GoTo Err

    Dim NewMail As Object
    Dim mailConfig As Object
    Dim fields As Variant
    Dim msConfigURL As String

    Set NewMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set mailConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    ' load all default configurations
    mailConfig.Load -1
    Set fields = mailConfig.fields

    'Set All Email Properties
    With NewMail
        .Subject = "Sales Follow up"
        .From = ""
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
    End With

    msConfigURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration"

    With fields
        'Enable SSL Authentication
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpusessl") = True

        'Make SMTP authentication Enabled=true (1)
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpauthenticate") = 1

        'Set the SMTP server and port Details
        'To get these details you can get on Settings Page of your Gmail Account
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserverport") = 465
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendusing") = 2

        'Set your credentials of your Gmail Account
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendusername") = "********"
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendpassword") = "********"

        'Update the configuration fields
        .Update
    End With

    NewMail.Configuration = mailConfig
    NewMail.send
    MsgBox ("Mail has been Sent")

Exit_Err:

    Set NewMail = Nothing
    Set mailConfig = Nothing
    End

Err:


    Select Case Err.Number
        Case -2147220973  'Could be because of Internet Connection
            MsgBox " Could be no Internet Connection !!  -- " & Err.Description
        Case -2147220975  'Incorrect credentials User ID or password
            MsgBox "Incorrect Credentials !!  -- " & Err.Description
        Case Else   'Rest other errors
            MsgBox "Error occured while sending the email !!  -- " & Err.Description
    End Select

    Resume Exit_Err

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont understand what was changed here.  I am needing to send the active worksheet in the email body.  it is somewhat urgent.  Any help would be great!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried `.AddAttachment`?

Comment: No I haven't.  I am not wanting to add it as an attachment.  Juat have that data that is shown on the sheet to be in the email

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to attach the sheet but simply show the data (and assuming that sending a mail in HTML is okay):

The following function creates a html-table from an Excel-Range

```
Function RangeToHtmlTable(r As Range)

    Dim data, row As Long, col As Long, html As String
    data = r.Value2
    html = "<table>"
    For row = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        html = html & "<tr>"
        For col = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            html = html & "<td>" & data(row, col) & "</td>"
        Next col
        html = html & "</tr>" & vbCrLf
    Next row
    html = html & "</table>"
    RangeToHtmlTable = html
End Function
```

Call of the function - simply replace `activesheet.usedRange` with whatever Range of data you want to send:

```
 With NewMail
    ...
    .HTMLBody = "<h1>Here is your data</h1>" & RangeToHtmlTable(activesheet.usedRange)
end with
```

**Update**: To send the data without html formatting:

```
Function RangeToTable(r As Range, Optional separator As String = vbTab)

    Dim data, row As Long, col As Long, table As String
    data = r.Value2
    table = ""
    For row = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        For col = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            table = table & data(row, col) & separator
        Next col
        table = table & vbCrLf
    Next row
    RangeToTable = table
End Function
```

When not sending html, you should assign the text to `.TextBody` rather than `.HTMLBody`. With the optional parameter `separator`, you can define what you want to show between cells (could be for example `"; "`)

```
.TextBody = "Here is your data:" & vbrLf & vbCrLf & RangeToTable(activesheet.usedRange)
```

Comment: Will this work with the current code that I have written?

Comment: For me it worked - just try it. Don't forget to set `.from` and `.to`.

Comment: So it works!  now im just having some formatting issues in the email such as just bold text.  And I am not sure how to set the range of what information i want to send.

Comment: this is what i want to see. https://ibb.co/gyGnWd
This is what i am seeing. https://ibb.co/mD5grd

Comment: Either you send the sheet as attachment or you have to do the formatting in html by your own. I don't see any other way.

Comment: alright, i think i can deal with the formatting issue.  but how to i choose the range of cells i want to show in the email?

Comment: also is there a way to send just the sheet data in an email and ignore the HTML formatting?

Comment: I have added a second function to create a text version. But I cannot really help you to choose the worksheet and the range. Try `usedRange` for a start.

Comment: Any chance I could get the code configured to use in a WORD doc.  my agents are having a hard time with the excel file for some reason.

Id like it to do that same thing, just sending the document information.